# Please unban my account, reason: many low-quality questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I'm starting to learn Java Swing, so I have many low-quality questions.
But I don't know where to post low-quality (or newbie) questions?
And I have some wrong tags (tag indexing) because I'm a newbie at Stack OverFlow and Java Swing.
My account don't have the right to ask anymore...

Comment: Low-quality questions are off topic everywhere on the network.

Comment: Being a newbie doesn't give you an excuse to post low quality questions, and neither does being a newbie automatically mean all your questions are low quality. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask again.

Comment: Instead of reflexively posting a question whenever you have a problem, try using the search box instead. Chances are, if you're having a problem with something, someone else has already experienced the same thing, asked a high-quality question, and gotten a high-quality answer.

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can get unbanned is to post good quality answers. If you have deleted questions, undelete them and edit them. Edit your current questions and get people to notice them.

Banning is an automatic thing; there is no human behind it, and as such, unbanning is automatic as well.

Basically, if you want to get unbanned, edit your current questions and answer other people's questions. Do not, in any circumstances, ever create a new account. That could lead to more serious consequences.

Comment: If a low-quality question of newbie get so many vote down, it should be deleted. How could newbie have quality answers to get enough vote to remove vote down?

Comment: No matter how newbie-ish you are, there is always someone who knows less than you, or someone who doesn't know something you know.. Answer those questions